# Is it possible to enable PCI USB controller from GRUB2 console?

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu LiveUSB on EPoX EP-4BDAE motherboard (it's 10 years old). It has "USB-*" options in BIOS boot setup, but It has never recognized any of my flash drives. Now it has USB-2.0 PCI Controller and I've seen *setpci* command in GRUB2 console. It still didn't recognize anything plugged in (there is only hd0 in auto-completion list): nor Nokia N900 in "Mass storage" mode neither Transcend HDD TS500GSJ25M. Can I somehow somehow start this PCI with GRUB's setpci?

Comment: Ok, I've successfully booted directly from iso using http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293

Comment: Can you post your answer as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a direct answer but I've successfully booted (and installed Ubuntu) directly from iso using GRUB2 console: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293